# Are $x^2+1$ and $x+1$ the same in $\mathbb{Z}_2[x]$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

> Are $x^2+1$ and $x+1$ the same in $\mathbb{Z}_2[x]$?

I can imagine two answers for this (and hopefully someone can tell me which one, if any, is the right one):

- Yes, because under the “Evaluation homomorphism” $x^2+1$ and $x+1$ are the same.

That is, evaluating $x^2+1$ at $0$ and $1$ gives the same results as evaluating $x+1$ at $0$ and $1$.

- No, $x^2+1$ and $x+1$ are different (formal expressions).

This means we should treat the polynomials as formal expressions and ignore the fact that under evaluation they are the same. Evaluation is irrelevant.

Any help?

Comment: I think you've answered your own question - it depends on how you want to interpret the phrase "the same".  Which interpretation is more appropriate would depend on the particular problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: Well, I think you answered the question yourself. Treating them as formal elements in $\mathbb{Z}_2[x]$, the two are different; treating them as polynomial functions from $\mathbb{Z}_2$ to $\mathbb{Z}_2$, they are the same.

Comment: Hmmm... Let’s say in the context of ideals. Would it be correct to say the ideals generated by the two polynomials are the same? How about the quotient spaces formed by modding out these ideals?

Comment: It sounds like you want to talk about the polynomials then. So no, these are not the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two different things:

- for any $x\in \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$, $x^2+1=x+1$;
- the polynomials $x^2+1$ and $x+1\in \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}[x]$ are different.

Depending on what meaning you give to "$x^2+1=x+1$ in $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$", one of these answers apply.

Answer (score 3):

What you have written is correct. Viewed as functions $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}\to \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$, $x^2+1$ and $x+1$ are identical. As elements of the ring $(\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})[x]$ they are necessarily distinct. Indeed, one is degree $2$ while the other is degree $1$.